Density of States, Photoemission and Integrating the Number of States
I'm reading Fowler's theory on photoemission. I'm stuck on a part which Fowler helpfully identifies as "obvious". Fowler sets up the free electron model, suggesting that electrons need a kinetic energy greater than the barrier potential $\chi_{0}$ to be emitted.
The number of electrons per unit volume, $n(v_{x})$ with the component normal to the material is given by
$$
 n(v_{x}) \mathrm{d}v_{x} =\underbrace{\frac{4\pi k_{b} T}{m} \bigg(\frac{m}{h}\bigg)^{3}}_{C=\text{constant}} \log\bigg[1+e^{(\epsilon_{F}-\frac{1}{2}m v_{x}^{2})/k_{b}T}\bigg] \mathrm{d}v_{x},
$$
where $\epsilon_{f}$ is the fermi energy, and all other symbols have their usual meanings. Now, Fowler integrates to find $N$ the number of electrons available with a kinetic energy above the barrier potential $\chi_0$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
N & =\int_{\frac{1}{2} m v_{x}^2=\mathrm{x}_0-h \nu}^{\infty} n(v_{x})\  \mathrm{d}v_{x}\\
& = \frac{C}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2 k_{b} T}{m}} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log \left[1+e^{-y+(h \nu-\chi_{0} + \epsilon_F) / k_{b} T}\right]}{\sqrt{y+\left(\chi_0-h \nu\right) / k_{b} T}} d y
\end{aligned}
$$
Fowler says the step is "obvious" for the above equation (computing the integral). . I don't see the substitution for $u \rightarrow y$ or other conceptual step that allows the substitution.

Do you want to understand how to compute the integral or you do not understand the expression for $n(v_x)$?

Let be $y = mv_x^2+h\nu-\chi_0$, then $dy=mv_x,dv_x$ and now we integrate from $0$ to $\infty$. Next just express $v_x$ via $y$ variable and the square root in denominator appears. In some sense it is indeed obvious. Also it seems that the sign at $\epsilon_F$ in the last line should be $+$, i.e. $+\epsilon_F$ instead of $-\epsilon_F$.

Just the computation of the integral. Thank you.

The substitution is $y=(mv_x+h\nu-\chi_0)/(k_bT)$. With this substitution, you obtain the desired form of the integral

I think that substitution missing a half, e.g. $y = (mv_{x}/2+h\nu+...)$. Stupid I didn't see this last night......
